# display image in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement on mouse over on the table, image one will display and on mouse over of the image one, a tooltip will display. When I click on tooltip link test, image two has to display inside td and previous image one should hide.

Issue is image two is getting displayed but I can see only if I mouse over on the table. How can I show image two once I click on tooltip link test without mouse over?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/45/.

**CSS :**

```
td.myData > img  
{
    display: none;
    float: right;
    height: 19px;
}

td.myData:hover > img 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function test(data)
{
    alert('test invoked with data: ' + data);
    var two = document.getElementById('two');
    two.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: Do not use the same id more than once per element. Also start thinking about selecting elements by jQuery, not a mix between raw js and jQuery. That will end in confusing effects for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test data script add the display block/none part like this,

```
<script>
      function test(data){
        alert("test invoked with data: " + data);
     var two = document.getElementById('two');
         two.style.visibility = 'visible';
         two.style.display = 'block';
      var one = document.getElementById('one');
         one.style.visibility = 'hidden';
         one.style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

code snippet follows...

```js
$(function() {
  var rowData;
  $(document).tooltip({
    items: "img, [data-title]",
    content: function() {
      var element = $(this);
      if (element.is("img")) {
        rowdata = element.attr("data-title");
        $(document).off('click', '#test');
        $(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
          test(rowdata);
        });


      }

      return $(this).prop('title');
    },
    show: null,
    close: function(event, ui) {
      ui.tooltip.hover(

        function() {
          $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(1000, 1);
        },

        function() {
          $(this).stop(true).fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
          })
        });
    },
    position: {
      my: "left",
      at: "right"
    }
  });
});



$(function() {
  $('.one').attr('title', $('.myTooltipTable').remove().html());
  $(document).tooltip();
});
```

```css
td.myData > img {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  height: 19px;
}
td.myData:hover > img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function test(data) {
    alert("test invoked with data: " + data);
    var two = document.getElementById('two');
    two.style.visibility = 'visible';
    two.style.display = 'block';
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    one.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table class="myTooltipTable" style="position:absolute;">
  <tr>
    <td> <span id="test">test</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="myData">Data1
      <img class="one" id="one" data-title="Data1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" alt="" />
      <img class="two" id="two" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" width="15" height="15" style="visibility:hidden;" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="myData">Data2
      <img class="one" id="one" data-title="Data2" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" alt="" />
      <img class="two" id="two" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" width="15" height="15" style="visibility:hidden;" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="myData">Data3
      <img class="one" id="one" data-title="Data3" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" alt="" />
      <img class="two" id="two" src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" width="15" height="15" style="visibility:hidden;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this was what you were looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
two.style.display = 'block';
```

to your `test` method. Currently you're just setting the `visibility` property but  the `display` property is still set to `none` in the CSS, so the image isn't rendering until you hover over it.

**See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/47/**